# How to get the attribut option value text by the value id?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute

I have an attribute with the name "staerke" and a few option fields like 1mm, 2mm, 3mm and so on.

I know the attribute id of the attribute and i have the id of the option value.
In my case the attribute "staerke" has the attribut-id 267 and the value for "5mm" has the id 239.

How can i get the value text of 5mm in my code when i have the id 239.

This is my code to get the id 239 ($thicknessId)

```
$newProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($newProductId);
$thicknessId = $newProduct->getData('staerke');
```

My last problem is to get the value "5mm" back from this id.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've loaded your product already, you can use `$thicknessId = $newProduct->getAttributeText('staerke')` to get the label of the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value directly with :

```
$_staerke = Mage::helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($newProduct, $newProduct->getAttributeText('staerke'), 'staerke');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
1. $attributeText = $product->getAttributeText('staerke');

2. $attributeText = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('staerke')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

3. $attributeText = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('staerke')->getFrontend()->getAttribute()->getFrontendLabel();
```